# How to design the button similar to compose button in Android gmail app

Tags: android

I need to design a button shown in this image. On click of the green button shown in the image few options should pop up. Can any one help me in doing this in Android application.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use FloatingActionButton from android design support library: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

You will need to include this dependency in your apps build.gradle file to reference it:

```
com.android.support:design:22.2.0
```

Here's a great reference:
http://antonioleiva.com/floating-action-button/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without the design support lib - which would be a slightly more difficult approach. I don't like the design lib approach because it adds some unnecessary permissions to Android Manifest via the manifest merger, and adds bunch of code I don't need (and I can change the compile API level to whatever I want).

So, basically - you would need a layout container (i.e. a RelativeLayout), and inside it you would put your main layout (a toolbar, list, buttons, etc). Then, alongside those items, you can [put a simple ImageView to the bottom right](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Position), but [spaced a bit](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#) from screen edges. Then you can make a 9-patch with shadow included for its background, AND for API21+ you can create a [circle shape drawable](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#shape), and [add some elevation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html) to it (this will generate a shadow).

If you want it to move, fade out, fade in, etc. you will need to do these things manually, which makes it advanced in comparison to the design lib approach.